# How to overwrite a folder if it already exists when creating it with makedirs?

Tags: python, directory, text-files, overwrite

The following code allows me to create a directory if it does not already exist.

```
dir = 'path_to_my_folder'
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

The folder will be used by a program to write text files into that folder. But I want to start with a brand new, empty folder next time my program opens up.

Is there a way to overwrite the folder (and create a new one, with the same name) if it already exists?

Comment: It should be noted, though it may not matter to you, that all of the answers here have race conditions (and while it's not really possible to eliminate them completely as posed, you could do better, by using EAFP).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

dir = 'path_to_my_folder'
if os.path.exists(dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
os.makedirs(dir)
```

Answer (score 33):

```
import os
import shutil

path = 'path_to_my_folder'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
else:
    shutil.rmtree(path)           # Removes all the subdirectories!
    os.makedirs(path)
```

How about that? Take a look at [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)'s `Python` library!

Comment: This also works.. But is this a fairly common module? This code needs to be implemented on many machines..

Comment: @ShankarKumar Yes. `shutil` is part of `Python`'s built in libraries since `Python 2.4`. I personally think `shutil` is better than `os` due some simplifications it does bring in.

Comment: Thank you so much, bro! CRACK

Answer (score 14):

`os.path.exists(dir)` check is recommended but can be avoided by using `ignore_errors`

```
dir = 'path_to_my_folder'
shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=True)
os.makedirs(dir)
```

Comment: Why ```os.path.exists(dir)``` is recommended? Does ```os.path.exists(dir)``` have any advantages comaring to your method?

Comment: @Ali_Sh idiomatic practice in Python “it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission”. Here ignore_errors does the same.

Comment: @Ali_Sh, ignore_errors ignore all errors, not just missing directory errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just say

```
dir = 'path_to_my_folder'
if not os.path.exists(dir): # if the directory does not exist
    os.makedirs(dir) # make the directory
else: # the directory exists
    #removes all files in a folder
    for the_file in os.listdir(dir):
        file_path = os.path.join(dir, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path) # unlink (delete) the file
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Do you mind explaining the logic behind it? I'm a beginner so I'm trying to learn as much as I can!

Comment: This would fail though, if you had subdirs in the dir you're trying to delete. Then you'd want to call `os.walk` to fix that. A simpler solution would be to use `shutil.rmtree`.

Comment: Would that be immune to race conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission) version:

```
import errno
import os
from shutil import rmtree
from uuid import uuid4

path = 'path_to_my_folder'
temp_path = os.path.dirname(path)+'/'+str(uuid4())
try:
    os.renames(path, temp_path)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.ENOENT:
        raise
else:
    rmtree(temp_path)
os.mkdir(path)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This came to me for review as your first answer. When answering an old question with an accepted answer, it's worth highlighting what you are adding to the existing solutions. In this case - can you explain why you believe that this code is immune to the race conditions? For instance - what happens if a file is written to the directory after the call to glob.iglob() - can you describe a reason why your solution is less subject to race condition? Also: you might think about explaining what EAFP stands for. *NB I've re-posted edited comment due to error in original*

Comment: @JRichardSnape Yes, you're right, this code is not immune to the race conditions. The new version, in my opinion, satisfy this requirement

Comment: I think it would be easier to just do `try: os.mkdir(path) except FileExistsError: shutil.rmtree(path) os.mkdir(path)`

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

Comment: This doesn't override the directory. It just makes the directory if it doesn't exist.