# Python: How to create a directory and overwrite an existing one if necessary?

Tags: python

I want to create a new directory and remove the old one if it exists. I use the following code:

```
if os.path.isdir(dir_name):
    shutil.rmtree(dir_name)
os.makedirs(dir_name)
```

It works, if the directory does not exist.

It errors if the directory does exist and the program in run normally. (WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'my_directory')

However, it also works if the directory already exists and the program is executed in debug mode line by line. I guess `shutil.rmtree()` and `makedirs()` need some time in between their calls.

What is the correct code so that it doesn't create an error?

Comment: I believe the reason you get that error is because you do not have read permission on the directory you are trying to delete. To give this permission, type `chmod +r directory_name` and you should have permissions for it.

Comment: @PiJoules That does not explain why it works when debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python a statement is executed just when the previous statement have finished, thats how an interpreter works.

My guess is that `shutil.rmtree` tell the filesystem to delete some directory tree and in that moment Python gives terminate the work of that statement --*even if the filesystem have not deleted the complete directory tree*--. For that reason, if the directory tree is big enough, when Python get to the line `os.makedirs(dir_name)` the directory can still to exist.

A faster operation (faster than deleting) is to rename the directory:

```
import os
import tempfile
import shutil

dir_name = "test"

if (os.path.exists(dir_name)):
    # `tempfile.mktemp` Returns an absolute pathname of a file that 
    # did not exist at the time the call is made. We pass
    # dir=os.path.dirname(dir_name) here to ensure we will move
    # to the same filesystem. Otherwise, shutil.copy2 will be used
    # internally and the problem remains.
    tmp = tempfile.mktemp(dir=os.path.dirname(dir_name))
    # Rename the dir.
    shutil.move(dir_name, tmp)
    # And delete it.
    shutil.rmtree(tmp)


# At this point, even if tmp is still being deleted,
# there is no name collision.
os.makedirs(dir_name)
```

Comment: I just ran your code a couple of time. It works. Thanks.

Comment: @ThS I'm glad to help, Do not forget upvote and check as answered.

Comment: I'd like to, but I don't have necessary reputation of 15.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
import shutil
import os

dir = '/path/to/directory'
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
else:
    shutil.rmtree(dir)           
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

Comment: This really don't improve the OP's code. And neither explain why the OP is getting that error. Besides your answer is too similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660605/python-overwriting-folder-if-it-already-exists

Comment: I agree with @RaydelMiranda