# Use pathlib to destructively rename one directory to another existing directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I have a directory structure that might look something like

```
Data
    Current
        A
        B
        C
    Previous
        A
        X
```

In as simple/quick a step as possible, I want to rename `Current` as `Previous` including the contents and wiping out the original such that it is now:

```
 Data
    Previous
        A
        B
        C
```

I've tried something like:

```
from pathlib import Path
src = Path('Data/Current')
dest = Path('Data/Previous')
src.replace(dest)
```

The docs led me to hope this would work:

> If target points to an existing file or directory, it will be
>   unconditionally replaced.

But it **does** appear to be conditional. I get a `Directory not empty` exception. I guess I could recursively delete the `Previous` directory first. Is that basically the only solution? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

(I prefer `pathlib`, but if `os` or `shutil` is the better hammer here, I'm not opposed to them)

(I am running on Linux)

Comment: I think the only way to go here is to first remove the dst if it exists.  shutil.rmtree() seems like a reasonable hammer in this case. This question is possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660641/3776268

Comment: I just experience the same thing with Python 3.9. The target was not unconditionally replaced, instead an error was displayed: "[Errno 17] File exists: '[src]' -> '[target]'".  Not a duplicate question, because this specifically relates to `Path.replace()` and its documented behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from sehafoc's comment, after removing the entire file tree for `dest` ("Data/Previous") using `shutil` this way:

```
shutil.rmtree(dest)
```

Rename `src` ("Data/Current") to `dest` .

```
src.rename(dest)
```